# Configure IIS to use specified directory in Grunt

Tags: iis, gruntjs

I am trying to configure IIS to use a specified directory in Grunt. Installing IIS creates the 'Default Web Site' and sets the path for this.

I am trying to make Grunt configure IIS to use a set directory depending on the machine it is on.

The way I have tried to do this is by using this site: https://www.npmjs.com/package/grunt-iis#options-path

I have used various options and tasks, even down to just using your_target and physicalPath. But I have had no luck.

```
grunt.initConfig({
  iis: {
    developer: {
      physicalPath : __dirname,
      site : 'Default Web Site',
      path : 'NewSite',
      pool : 'NewSite',
      managedRuntimeVersion : 'v4.0'
    }
  },
});
```

Please can someone help me with this.

Thanks, 
Sam

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have done this using exec command: command:

```
exec: {    
    command: 'c:\\Windows\\System32\\inetsrv\\appcmd.exe set vdir \"Default Web Site/\" -physicalPath:\"path"',
    stdout: false,
    stderr: false
          },
    },
});
```